# How to not show tests conditionally

Tags: c#, nunit

There are some tests in my code which are not valid for some types, for example, type T1, type T2.. and I don't want to show those tests in the test explorer that are not valid for particular types.

For example:

```
// this test is not valid for type T1, so I don't want to display this test in Test Explorer when the T1 is enabled.
[Test]
[Ignore test if type == "T1"]
public void testSomeParameter() 
{
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not valid for some types"?

Comment: Maybe you want to use categories...

Comment: Like my given example, testSomeParameter() is not a valid test for type T1, so when the tests run for type T1 then we don't want to show testSomeParameter() in the test explorer.

Comment: How to use categories in this case?

Comment: I'm sure you have a good understanding of what you mean by "run for some type". I can think of three or four alternates, which I won't bother listing here. You have to tell us what __you__ mean. Showing some code that indicates how and where you tell the test what Type it is being run for is the best way to do that.